# On key down, abort a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've just started learning C# and I'm trying to figure out threads.

So, I've made a two threads and I would like to stop one of them by pressing x.

So far when I press x it only shows on the console but it doesn't abort the thread.

I'm obviously doing something wronng so can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            //Creating Threads
            Thread t1 = new Thread(Method1)
            {
                Name = "Thread1"
            };
            Thread t4 = new Thread(Method4)
            {
                Name = "Thread4"
            };

            t1.Start();
            t4.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Method4 has started. Press x to stop it. You have 5 SECONDS!!!");
            var input = Console.ReadKey();
            string input2 = input.Key.ToString();

            Console.ReadKey();
            if (input2 == "x")
            {
                t4.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS! You have stoped Thread4! Congrats.");
            };
            Console.Read();

        }

        static void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method1 Started using " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method1: " + i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Method1 Ended using " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        }

        static void Method4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method4 Started using " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method4: " + i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Method4 Ended using " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Don't abort threads, it can leave your program in a unstable state. Learn and try to implement "Cooperative cancelation" instead, Here is a [article from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) about how to properly cancel managed threads. With the knowledge from the article you can then do "On key down Cancel a thread" instead of aborting the thread.

Comment: thank you. I'll check it out

Comment: Aborting threads is a [no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort), and also not supported in .NET Core. You get an unconditional `PlatformNotSupportedException` on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a extra `Console.ReadKey();` before `if (input2 == "x")`, that extra read causes the program to stop and wait before going inside your `if` statement waiting for a 2nd key to be pressed.

Also `input.Key` returns a [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=netcore-3.1), when you do the to string on it the enum will use a capital X because that is what it is set to. Either use `input.KeyChar.ToString()` to convert it to a string or use

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();
if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
```

To compare against the enum instead of a string.

I also recommend you read the article "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)", debugging is a skill you will need to learn to be able to write more complex programs. Stepping through the code with a debugger you would have seen `input2` was equal to `X` so your if statement was

```
if ("X" == "x")
```

which is not true.

Comment: That clears some of the things up. Thank you for the help.